# How to get superscript in form edit field

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a crossword type puzzle using html and php.
I have a form edit field where the user can type 1 letter.
The edit field is in a table cell.

```
        <td><input type='text' maxlength='1' name='$identifier' value='$value'    text-align:center;' size='1px'></td>
```

Since it's a crossword, I would like to be able to display a number at the top left of the table cell in superscript.
I've been trying to put it before the input cell with the sup tag, but this puts it outside of the edit field. I've also played around with the "placeholder" attribute, but that will make the number disappear when you type, which is not the effect I'm after. How do I get a permanent superscript number in my table cell? I'd love some help!

Comment: Use CSS. make `<td>` position to `relative` and create a span tag inside the `<td>` with the number inside it like `<span>1</span>` and make it position to `absolute` and `top:0;left:0;` so it would be place on the top left corner of `<td>`

Comment: Thanks Mark! I didn't think about using a span. Going to try it out. Appreciate your help!

Comment: The top: 0; left:0; put it at the top left of my entire screen, but with only the absolute position, it works like a charm. Thanks so much!!!!!

Comment: I posted a sample answer.

Answer (score 2):

It would be something like this if you use span

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
  position: relative;
}
table td input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}
table td span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 8px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td><span>1</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>2</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>3</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>4</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>5</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>6</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>7</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>8</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>9</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>10</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>11</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>12</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>13</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>14</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>15</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>16</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>17</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>18</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>19</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>20</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>21</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>22</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>23</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>24</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
    <td><span>25</span>
      <input type='text' maxlength='1' name='' value='' style='  text-align:center;' size='1px'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6268ugbd/

Comment: Thanks so much Mark!